# What's the opposite of "happy to"?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, expressions, antonyms

When I need to deliver someone an unfortunate news, what would be the opposite phrase to:

> I'm happy to inform you...

or

> I'm delighted to give you this news...

Comment: "It is sadly that I inform you that..."

Comment: "It is with sadness that . . ." is (50x, according to raw Google data) more common. These work in less intimate correspondence. 'I'm so sorry  – have you heard that . . .' would be more tactful.

Comment: "With a heavy heart"

Comment: @Em1 Sounds great, although not formal enough in my context :-)

Comment: *Sorry*. (That's the answer, I mean.)

Comment: @Nanda "It is sadly that I inform you that..."  I gather there are dialects of English where this is normal, but no Brit would say this. Though it sounds kind of cute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the option that best suits my purpose:

> I regret to inform you...

Comment: I would vote this answer up except for its claim of *best*.

Comment: @bib I didn't mean it's the best out there, I meant that it best suits my purpose :-)

Answer (score 6):

I am (very) sorry to inform you...

Answer (score 2):

I am reluctant to inform you that...

Or, what you've hinted at in your original post:

"Unfortunately, you didn't win."